How to get web app class loader from a TestNG module?
MyServerClass running under Jetty uses Logback classic:
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServerClass.class);`

In a separate Maven module for TestNG & Selenium Webdriver I'm trying to attach a logback LoggerContextListener to that logger.
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServerClass.class);
LoggerContext loggerContext = logger.getLoggerContext();
loggerContext.addListener(new MyLoggerContextListener());

The problem is the class loaders are different for the 2 modules
so LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServerClass.class) returns a different instance
to that running in the server module & MyServerClass.logger so in MyServerClass
loggerContext.getCopyOfListenerList();

remains empty.
In the server module:
ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
String path = servletContext.getContextPath();

path is an empty string, which means it's the "root" context, rooted at the base of the Webserver's URL name space.
In the tests module:
I read somewhere that Jetty provides ServletContextHelper which can return the webAppClassLoader which should be able to provide Jetty's instance of MyServerClass to which the Listener can be added:
ServletContext servletContext = ServletContextHelper.getServletContext(path);
ClassLoader webAppClassLoader = servletContext.getClassLoader();
Class<?> MyServerClass = webAppClassLoader.loadClass("com.example.MyServerClass");
Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServerClass.class);
LoggerContext loggerContext = logger.getLoggerContext();
loggerContext.addListener(new MyLoggerContextListener());

I can't find this ServletContextHelper in the Jetty jars.
Any suggestions appreciated.

In Jetty 12, just use the addHiddenClassMatcher() on the WebAppContext
import org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ClassMatcher;

WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
// other init of webapp
webapp.addHiddenClassMatcher(new ClassMatcher("ch.qos.logback"));


Thanks: I didn't try this because it now seems on attaching a listener in the tests module directly to the server instance of LoggerContext with logger.getLoggerContext().addListener, the listener can throw WebDriverException or AssertionError but these  fail to trigger a test failure, as they would if called from the test module code. I ended up using JMS messaging between the modules. I couldn't find anything about how to fail a test on logback error, Gemini suggested JMS.
